# jfreechart multiple renderers tooltip not working

Tags: jfreechart, label, renderer

[image]I have a figure with 2 sets of graphs (detections and localizations). First set (localizations) is red ,orange,pink and second set (detections) is blue,black,cyan. I have created a renderer for each set in order to set the colors. I have set the tooltip to true but when I mouseover on the second set (detection) I can't see the labels. I can see labels only for first set on mouseover(see picture) but not for the other set. Here is my code:

```
    JFreeChart avg_chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            "Average detections and localizations" ,
            "" ,
            "" ,
            null ,
            true , true , false);
    avg_chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);

    final XYPlot plot = avg_chart.getXYPlot( );
    plot.setDataset(0,this.dataset_local);
    plot.setDataset(1,this.dataset_detect);
    plot.setRangeAxis(0,new NumberAxis("Localizations"));
    plot.setRangeAxis(1,new NumberAxis("Detections"));

    plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(0, 0);
    plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1, 1);

    plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
    plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);

    XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer1 = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer(0);//localization
    renderer1.setSeriesPaint( 0 , Color.RED );
    renderer1.setSeriesPaint( 1 , Color.MAGENTA );
    renderer1.setSeriesPaint( 2 , Color.orange );
    renderer1.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);

    XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer2 = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, false); //detection ****************
    renderer2.setSeriesPaint( 0 , Color.BLUE);
    renderer2.setSeriesPaint( 1 , Color.BLACK );
    renderer2.setSeriesPaint( 2 , Color.CYAN );
    renderer2.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);

    plot.setRenderer(0,renderer1);
    plot.setRenderer(1,renderer2);

    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
    axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    return avg_chart;

}
```

I have tried XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer2 = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer(1) but it gives be a nulll exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createTimeSeriesChart-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset-boolean-boolean-boolean-) adds an `XYToolTipGenerator` to `renderer1` for you when `tooltips` is `true`. You probably just need to use it with `renderer2`:

```
renderer2.setBaseToolTipGenerator(renderer1.getBaseToolTipGenerator());
```

Or you can add a new one to `renderer2`:

```
XYToolTipGenerator toolTipGenerator2 = StandardXYToolTipGenerator.getTimeSeriesInstance();
renderer2.setBaseToolTipGenerator(toolTipGenerator2);
```